# How to limit number of selected values to be display from multi select dropdown in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

This is my multi-select dropdown control taken from this source:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-multi-select-dropdown

but problem is if i am having 50 values in my dropdown and if i am selecting all values from dropdown then that div in which those selected values are displayed becomes so large.

so i just want 4 to 5 values to be displayed instead on 50 values.

This is my View:

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController">
 <multi-select input-model="MyList"
                      button-label="name"
                      item-label="name"
                      tick-property="ticked">
        </multi-select>
    </div>
```

My script:

```
 <script>
        angular.module("myapp", [])
        .controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
           $scope.MyList= [];
      $scope.MyList= [
        { firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Parker", pic: "<img src='[...]/peter.png  />", selected: false },
        { firstName: "Mary", lastName: "Jane", pic: "<img src='[...]/mary.png   />", selected: false },
        { firstName: "Bruce", lastName: "Wayne", pic: "<img src='[...]/bruce.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "David", lastName: "Banner", pic: "<img src='[...]/david.png  />", selected: false },
        { firstName: "Natalia", lastName: "Romanova", pic: "<img src='[...]/nat.png    />", selected: false },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true }
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
        { firstName: "Clark", lastName: "Kent", pic: "<img src='[...]/clark.png  />", selected: true },
            ];
 </script>
```

Now if i am selecting all values from dropdown then i want to display only 4 to 5 selected values only.

can anybody please help me??

Comment: [Did you really read all of the documentation?](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/configs-options)

Comment: No.  I have no compelling reason to.  Please do not flood my global inbox with these messages.

Comment: If you have a different question to ask, ask a different question.  **Do not edit this question and replace it with a completely different one**.